# Variable might not have been initialized because it's used in another?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm having a trouble because one field is being used in another map field, and it looks like it does it before the other field is initialized. How can I fix that?

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CommandsHandler {

    private final StartCommand startCommand;

    public Map<String, BiFunction<Long, String, SendMessage>> COMMANDS = Map.of(
            "/start", (x,y) -> startCommand.apply(x,y)
    );
...
```

And `StartCommand` is:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class StartCommand {

    private final CityRepository repository;

...
```

Comment: Yeah, `COMMANDS` uses `startCommand`, but that one is initialized in the constructor. You'll need to also set `COMMANDS` in your constructor (which should be `commands` instead, and non-`public`).

Comment: @MCEmperor, I made commands private final but the problem still occurs

Comment: @MCEmperor, okay I just wrote my own constructor and got rid of @ required annotation since it wasn't working properly, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MCEmperor, he noticed that my `commands` variable wasn't `final` anymore hence meaning it's trying to use `startCommand` before it's initialized. However, just adding `final` doesn't help since `@RequiredArgsConstructor` isn't working how it's supposed too in that case, so I ended up adding normal constructor:

```
@Component
public class CommandsHandler {

    private final StartCommand startCommand;

    private final Map<String, BiFunction<Long, String, SendMessage>> commands;

    public CommandsHandler(@Autowired StartCommand startCommand) {
        this.startCommand = startCommand;
        this.commands = Map.of(
                "/start", startCommand::apply
        );
    }
```